# ABPersonViewController finished editing notification

Tags: objective-c, ios, addressbook

Using ABPersonViewController per Apple's Quick Contacts sample code.

```
ABRecordRef person = (ABRecordRef)[people objectAtIndex:0];
    ABPersonViewController *picker = [[[ABPersonViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    picker.personViewDelegate = self;
    picker.displayedPerson = person;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

I need a way of being notified that the picker has finished editing or has closed so I can update some cached values in my data store.

Apple's docs recommend staying away from subclassing ABPersonViewController. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    ABPersonViewController *personViewController = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];

        personViewController.personViewDelegate = self;
        personViewController.displayedPerson = person; 
        personViewController.allowsEditing=YES;
        personViewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Back",nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(ReturnFromPersonView)] ;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:personViewController animated:YES];
        [personViewController release];
```

then write your **ReturnFromPersonView** method and delegate method

```
- (BOOL)personViewController:(ABPersonViewController *)personViewController shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifierForValue
{
        // you can write you code here with  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        return YES;     
}
```

if you dont like "back button" method - you can write your code direct into personViewController shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:

Comment: Thank you :) I circumvented this issue by minimizing my redundant stores in core data (only keeping the record ID to reference) and retrieving the address book values when needed to maintain the most up-to-date values.